# Upload file (HTML5 canvas image → file) in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, reactjs, blob, filereader

Attempting to upload an image as a file per these instructions: https://github.com/graphcool-examples/react-graphql/blob/master/files-with-apollo/src/components/CreatePage.js#L48-L65

The above-referenced instructions work on mobile and desktop/laptop:

```
handleDrop(files) {
  let data = new FormData()
  data.append('data', person.avatar)
  fetch('https://api.graph.cool/file/v1/___PROJECTID___', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  })
  [...]
}
```

However, if instead of directly uploading an image, I want to crop it first. So I:

1. I save the file (using React) in the local state first,
2. Crop it,
3. Then upload it.

However, this process only seems to work on a desktop/laptop, but not on mobile. For mobile, an empty image is produced, with the error `InvalidStateError (DOM Exception 11): The object is in an invalid state.`

I wonder if it has to do with file storage limitations for mobile. Could a potential solution perhaps be to use `FileReader`?

Here’s the code that works on a desktop/laptop, but not on mobile:

```
handleDrop(files) {
  // First save file to local state
  this.setState({ file: file[0] })
}

// Image is then cropped, upon which handleCrop() is called

handleCrop() {
  // This returns a HTMLCanvasElement, it can be made into a data URL or a blob, drawn on another canvas, or added to the DOM.
  const image = this.refs.avatar.getImageScaledToCanvas().toDataURL()
  // Custom DataURLtoBlob() function
  const blob = DataURLtoBlob(image)
  let file = new File([blob], 'avatar.png', {
    lastModified: new Date(),
    type: "image/png"
  })
  let data = new FormData()
  data.append('data', file)
  fetch('https://api.graph.cool/file/v1/___PROJECTID___', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  })
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Don’t convert the `blob` back into a `File`. Instead, just upload the `blob`

```
handleDrop(files) {
  // First save file to local state
  this.setState({ file: file[0] })
}

// Image is then cropped, upon which handleCrop() is called

handleCrop() {
  // This returns a HTMLCanvasElement, it can be made into a data URL or a blob, drawn on another canvas, or added to the DOM.
  const image = this.refs.avatar.getImageScaledToCanvas().toDataURL()
  // Custom DataURLtoBlob() function
  const blob = DataURLtoBlob(image)
  let data = new FormData()
  data.append('data', blob)
  fetch('https://api.graph.cool/file/v1/___PROJECTID___', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  })
  [...]
}
```